# Mocking a directive in angularjs unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I know there is [$controllerProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$controllerProvider) which can be used, to create controllers inside unit tests. I'm wondering however if there is a way to mock a directive inside of a unit test.

The background to this is, that I'm trying to mock(! not to create) a directive which is applying an async validator to ngModel. Perfect would be something like this:

```
beforeEach(function () {
   module('myMod', function($directiveProvider) {
      $directiveProvider.register('mockAsyncValidationDirective', function() {
          return {
              restrict: 'EA',
              require: 'ngModel'
              // ...
          }
      });
   });
});
```

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to mock a directive (maybe there isn't one atm), but I was able to solve my specific issue, by accessing the model-controller via the form controller.

Here is the code:

```
    var scope = $rootScope.$new();

    var html = '<form name="testForm">' +
        '<input type="text" ng-model="username">' +
        '</form>';

    var element = $compile(html)(scope);
    var form = scope.testForm;
    var ngModel = form.username;


    ngModel.$asyncValidators.unique = function (modelValue, viewValue)
    {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $timeout(function ()
        {
            if (viewValue === 'NOT_UNIQUE') {
                deferred.reject();

            } else {
                deferred.resolve();
            }
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

I still would be interested in an answer on how to mock a full directive.